# Unable to enter Username and password in webpage using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, automation

I am trying to login to a webpage using VBA, but I am unable to get it done. The issue is after the username and password punched, when clicking the signin button the webpage gives an error as "Required field" so basically the credentials are not entered.

I have also tried to set the value to the attribute using IE.document.getElementById("email").setAttribute("Value") = "XX" but still is throws the same error. I have also tried .focus method too but no luck.

I hope I have explained my issue, kindly excuse for any errors.
The webpage link "" https://dashboard.stripe.com/login"" I cannot share the credentials as it is confidential."

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://dashboard.stripe.com/login"
Do Until Not IE.busy: DoEvents: Loop
Set doc = IE.document
Do While doc.ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop

IE.document.getelementbyid("email").Value = "a@A.com"
IE.document.getelementbyid("password").Value = "a"

Set ElementCol = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("span")
For Each link In ElementCol
If link.innerHTML = "Sign in to your account" Then
link.Click
End If
Next
```

Comment: I hit a recaptcha to prove not a robot when attempting login. Are you sure "scraping" is allowed?

Comment: And even if is, I think the captcha is going to be a difficult obstacle to overcome. Certainly not with VBA.

Comment: I think it is.The captcha will popup only once after a successful login on the same system it will not. Are you able to enter the credentials and hit sigin?

Comment: Hi QHarr, could you please post code you used with Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following with [selenium basic](https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/). After install go to VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to selenium type library.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub EnterInfo()
    Dim d As WebDriver, keys As New Selenium.keys
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const url = "https://dashboard.stripe.com/login"
    With d
        .AddArgument "--headless"
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get url
         .FindElementById("email").SendKeys "joe.blogs@aol.com"
         .FindElementById("password").SendKeys keys.Enter
        .FindElementById("password").SendKeys "password"
        .FindElementById("password").SendKeys keys.Enter
         .FindElementByTag("form").submit
         Stop '<== Delete me
        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help however I have not worked with Selenium so it will be hard for me too move further as I have to get information from the web page after login and navigate to different options to get the information.

Comment: Hi QHarr, I tried the above code but it gives me an error after I start the web browser.(The underlying connection was closed an unexpected error occurred on a receive) So I changed the browser to IE it works. Also you are correct the captcha seems to be a problem as it shows each and every time I login. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you have any solution for the error.

Comment: Hi QHarr, it has been a while. I had solved the captcha issue. Now the problem is I need to select the drop-down to change accounts, but I am unable to do it. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please post your solution for the captcha that will be useful for future readers. If you post a new question for the current problem and include the URL/HTML (as insert  using snippet tool not image) and drop me a line here I would love to help.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for my English, i actually asked the client to remove the secure option and add our IP as trusted and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes you should. But if you leave the link here I will have a look for sure.

Comment: And let me know whether you prefer a selenium solution, don't or don't care. If you want some general pointers when you have 20 points you can stop by the [dawghaus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169987/dawgs-waffle-haus) to ask general questions. There is more room literally to discuss things there.

Comment: Hi again, here is the link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228094/unable-to-select-from-dropdown-in-selenium-using-vba