# Unable to select from dropdown in selenium using vba

Tags: vba, excel, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Hi I am new to selenium via VBA, so I am trying to automate a process by loging into a webpage navigate and get data extracted into the excel file.
From what I have researched, first i have call the dropdown by click and then select the option.

Below is my code

```
Sub Praise()
Dim bot As New WebDriver
bot.Start "chrome"
bot.Get "https://dashboard.stripe.com/login"
bot.FindElementById("email").SendKeys ActiveCell.Value
bot.FindElementById("password").SendKeys ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
bot.FindElementByTag("form").submit
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:8"))
Set myelement = bot.FindElementByClass("bs-Link", Raise:=False)
If myelement Is Nothing Then
Else
bot.FindElementByClass("bs-Link").Click
End If
bot.FindElementByClass("db-AccountSwitcher-chevron").Click ' to call dropdown
bot.FindElementByClass("Text-color--white Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline").Click ' Error occurs in this line

End Sub
```

Here is the code to call dropdown

```html
<div class="db-AccountSwitcher-button Box-root Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center">
  <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
    <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-activeImage">
      <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
        <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--dark Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--noWrap Text-display--inline">Masorini.com</span></div>
  <div class="Box-root Margin-left--8">
    <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-chevron"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code of the dropdown list

```html
<div class="ScrollableMenu SearchableList-items" id="searchable-list-results-47" role="listbox" style="max-height: 200px;">
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Masorini.com</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Ariavoss</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Bikinimas</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Diva Noche</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="true" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--blue Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="Text-color--white Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Bootyswim</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Zainno</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Actiwears</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Rockactive</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Cat Lovers</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Chicnuit</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Bootyswim</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Diva Noche</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Bikinimas</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">EpicDevil.co</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">probago.com</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Activepose</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">SiaRose.com</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Sunvoss</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Mosselli</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Aroabikini</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">Swimlemon</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">milewatches</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--fallback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">stripe-northwrist@massiveshops.com</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-selected="false" role="option">
    <div>
      <div class="Box-root Box-background--white Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center" style="cursor: pointer; user-select: none;">
        <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8">
          <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage Box-root Box-background--white">
            <div class="db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--content db-AccountSwitcher-accountImage--newAccount"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--default Text-fontSize--16 Text-fontWeight--medium Text-lineHeight--24 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline">New account</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the error code

[image]

Comment: Does your code work to click the drop down? And what do you want to select from the drop down?

Comment: Yes it clicks and the list is visible on the screen, but when I use the same method to click the option from the list, it throws an error !! I have added the error code snippet !!

Comment: you need to remove spaces from the class name and replace them with dots.

Comment: what option are you trying to select by the way?

Comment: Actually this is a repeatable task so i need to select all the options, but one at a time, basically these are the clients different accounts. so when I select the right account then only I can find the pertaining information.

Comment: Ok... well try the solutions below and feedback :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the click part for this but you need to remove spaces from the class name to get rid of that error

```
bot.FindElementByCss(".Text-color--white.Text-fontSize--16.Text-fontWeight--medium.Text-lineHeight--24.Text-typeface--base.Text-wrap--wrap.Text-display--inline").Click
```

That targets `Bootyswim`

If click works then you should also be able to use:

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@role='option'][5]").Click
```

Then you change the `[5]` for your other options.

Try the xpath [here](http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=b0945340-1758-4f7e-a1b7-88ec9c2e96c8-xpath) and play with selecting your other options.

Comment: Hi QHarr, The following code works like a charm, bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@role='option'][5]").Click. Hurrah !!! I thank you so much !!

Comment: No worries. Pleased it helped.

Comment: Hi QHarr, sorry to bother you, I have again come to a halt, as I am unable to enter the text in a search box !! Here is the code - 

<div data-offset-key="dtaef-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr"><span data-offset-key="dtaef-0-0"><br data-text="true"></span></div>

Comment: Can you post in a new question so can clearly see the html and the problem? Put link here and I will look. Note: I don't see an input tag.

Comment: Here is the link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229206/unable-to-enter-value-in-search-box-using-selenium-via-vba

Comment: Hi QHarr, I have a similar question, would you mind having a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73426992/how-do-i-use-vba-selenium-to-select-an-option-in-a-html-dropdown-that-isnt-sele

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually click the drop down then select the value. You simply set the drop down field to the value you want it to be.

Here's my little code snippet that does this on a site I need to navigate.

```
Dim element As Selenium.WebElement
Set element = WaitForElement(byName, "Your element ID here")
element.AsSelect.SelectByText "The exact text that's in the drop down"
```

The first line calls the function below - I was running into timeout issues waiting for the website to finish loading, so I wrote that to be able to intelligently wait until the page loaded before giving up on not finding the element.

The second line explicitly sets the drop down to the value that I'm looking for - there's no clicking on the element and selecting.

```
Private Function WaitForElement(ByVal Method As FindElementBy, ByVal elementID As String) As Selenium.WebElement

  Dim startTimer As Single
  startTimer = Timer

  Dim waitTime As Single
  waitTime = this.Driver.Timeouts.ImplicitWait / 100

  Dim webBit As Selenium.WebElement
  On Error Resume Next    'it is possible that we'll go looking for the element before it's been returned to view, that's fine, we're waiting for it
  While webBit Is Nothing And Timer < (startTimer + waitTime)
    Select Case Method
      Case byClass
        Set webBit = this.Driver.FindElementByClass(elementID)
      Case byCSS
        Set webBit = this.Driver.FindElementByCss(elementID)
      Case byID
        Set webBit = this.Driver.FindElementById(elementID)
      Case byLinkText
        Set webBit = this.Driver.FindElementByLinkText(elementID)
      Case byName
        Set webBit = this.Driver.FindElementByName(elementID)
      Case byPartialLinkText
        Set webBit = this.Driver.FindElementByPartialLinkText(elementID)
      Case byTag
        Set webBit = this.Driver.FindElementByTag(elementID)
      Case byXPath
        Set webBit = this.Driver.FindElementByXPath(elementID)
    End Select
  Wend
  On Error GoTo 0         'resume normal error handling

  Set WaitForElement = webBit

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Freeman, thanks for the help, however since I am a newbie I am unable to understand, my webpage code does not have the ID element instead it has only ClassName element. so how do I tweak your code to fit my situation.

Comment: Replace `"Your element ID here"` with `"Your element name here"`. Also, you do not have to use the `WaitForElement` function, you can go directly to `bot.FindElementByName` as you've named it.

Comment: I _believe_ that in your case, `"Your element name here"` would be `"Bootyswim"` - that appears to be the text in the combo box that is currently selected.

Comment: This is interesting and I might nick if you don't mind. I am not sure it will work in this case as doesn't AsSelect require there to be a select tag?

Comment: @QHarr you're free to have it. This is what worked for me after several weeks of muddling through things. It's posted with an implicit "No guarantee of suitability to purpose. Use at your own risk."