# Unable to enter value in search box using selenium via VBA

Tags: vba, excel, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Hi I am new to selenium via VBA, so I am trying to automate a process by loging into a webpage navigate and get data extracted into the excel file. the problem is after login i am unable to input values in a search box.
Here are the codes i have tried

```
bot.FindElementById("placeholder-3vgh2").SendKeys "AAA"
bot.FindElementByClass(".public-DraftStyleDefault-block.public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr").SendKeys "AAA"
bot.FindElementByClass("public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr").SendKeys "AAA"
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@data-contents='true']").SendKeys "AAA"
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr']").SendKeys "AAA"
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@data-offset-key='dtaef-0-0'][2]").SendKeys "AAA"
```

Here is HTML Code

```html
<div class="db-World-topContent Box-root Box-background--surface Padding-vertical--20">
  <div class="Box-root Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center Flex-justifyContent--spaceBetween">
    <div class="db-SearchField db-SearchField--tokenizable">
      <div class="db-SearchField-input db-SearchField-input--highlighted">
        <div class="DraftEditor-root">
          <div class="DraftEditor-editorContainer">
            <div aria-describedby="placeholder-3vgh2" class="notranslate public-DraftEditor-content" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" spellcheck="false" style="outline: none; user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word;">
              <div data-contents="true">
                <div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="3vgh2" data-offset-key="dtaef-0-0">
                  <div data-offset-key="dtaef-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr"><span class="db-SearchField-token" data-offset-key="dtaef-0-0"><span data-offset-key="dtaef-0-0"><span data-text="true">is:</span></span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><span></span><span></span></div><span></span></div>
    <div class="Box-root">
      <div class="Box-root Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center Flex-direction--row Flex-justifyContent--flexStart" style="margin-left: -12px;">
        <div class="Box-root Box-hideIfEmpty Margin-left--12"></div>
        <div class="Box-root Box-hideIfEmpty Margin-left--12">
          <div class="Box-root Padding-right--8">
            <div class="db-FeedbackInput-container Card-root Card-shadow--small">
              <div class="db-FeedbackInput-box Box-root Box-background--offset Padding-horizontal--8 Padding-vertical--4 Flex-flex Flex-alignItems--center">
                <div class="Box-root Margin-right--8 Flex-flex"><span class="db-FeedbackInput-defaultIcon"></span></div>
                <div class="TruncatedText" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"><span class="Text-color--gray400 Text-fontSize--14 Text-fontWeight--regular Text-lineHeight--20 Text-typeface--base Text-wrap--wrap Text-display--inline"><span>Feedback about this page?</span></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Box-root Box-hideIfEmpty Margin-left--12">
          <div>
            <div class="Box-root Flex-flex">
              <div class="Box-root Flex-flex"><button aria-label="Documentation" class="db-DocumentationMenu-root" tabindex="-1"></button></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Box-root Box-hideIfEmpty Margin-left--12">
          <div>
            <div class="Box-root Flex-flex">
              <div class="Box-root Flex-flex">
                <div tabindex="-1" style="outline: none;"><button aria-label="Notifications" class="db-Notifications-button"><span class="db-Notifications-icon db-Notifications-icon--empty"></span></button></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Box-root Box-hideIfEmpty Margin-left--12">
          <div>
            <div class="Box-root Flex-flex">
              <div class="Box-root Flex-flex"><button class="bs-Button bs-DeprecatedButton db-UserMenu" aria-label="User menu" type="button" tabindex="-1"><div class="db-GravatarImage db-UserMenu-image db-GravatarImage--none"></div></button></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><span class="db-World-topContent--left"></span><span class="db-World-topContent--right"></span></div>
```

Here is the outerHTML of iframe:

```html
<iframe src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/m/outer.html#ping=false" style="width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; position: absolute !important; left: -10000px !important; top: -1000px !important;"></iframe>
```

Comment: I don't see an input tag. Which is the element where you are supposed to put text?

Comment: It is like a search box, when i type something it immediately tries to find as i type, just like google search box. I have pasted the entire code of the search box.

Comment: if on the page you select the box and right click inspect element what is the exact element in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, following our debug session:

```
bot.FindElementByCss(".notranslate.public-DraftEditor-content").SendKeys "AAA"
```

Comment: The follwing line works as I can see the cursor on the search box bot.FindElementByCss(".public-DraftStyleDefault-block.public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr").Click -- However after that I am unable to use send keys, this is code i used = bot.FindElementByCss(".public-DraftStyleDefault-block.public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr").SendKeys "AAA"

Comment: Hi Qharr, I am sorry for the delay, I tried both the above codes but getting error message.  For this code : bot.FindElementByCss(".public-DraftStyleDefault-block.public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr").Text = "yourText" = It says "Compile error: Assignment to constant not permitted"    For this code : bot.FindElementByCSS(".db-SearchField-token").SendKeys "yourText" = It says "NoSuchElementError Element not found for Css = ..db-SearchField-token

Comment: No it is not in a frame/form/ iframe tag. Actually when I click on the search box there is list of dropdown condition like (Is, last4 ,date, email, and so on ...) but its not a dropdown because i can enter the value (case number) and then it will automatically loads the result. In my case when we work manually I copy the case number from the excel and paste it in the search box then immediately it gives me the result

Comment: Hi, I just noticed in the inspect page when scroll down to the very bottom i see a tag as iframe but when i do Ctrl+shift+C and move the cursor nothing gets highlighted.

Comment: It is at the very bottom, no the element is at the top not in between them. I have pasted the outterHTML of the code in the question, hope this will help you !!

Comment: Not anymore though I have a copy of the HTML. Are you supposed to enter text after the **IS:** ?

Comment: I am sorry, I need to only the case number to be pasted because, once pasted it will automatically fetch the result from there i will extract the result to the excel.

Comment: Pasted where? Next to where on the page it says IS:  ?

Comment: We can discuss [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82977/selenium-discussion)

Comment: This worked for me bot.FindElementByCss(".notranslate.public-DraftEditor-content").SendKeys "AAA"