# Trouble with entering fields on a webpage via VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm creating a tool in Excel that will navigate through a webpage and pick out bits of data (idea is to be able to just hit this button and get updated data as and when required)

But I'm having trouble just getting past the log in page.

This is my code (I've taken out the webpage and log in details)

`Private Sub GoButton_Click()

```
Dim myURL As String
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As htmlDocument

myURL = "www.myWebPage"
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate myURL

    Do Until .READYSTATE = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Set doc = IE.document

    Call findObjectToClick("cmdSubmit") 'Click on Log in Button

    Do Until .READYSTATE = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Set doc = IE.document

    doc.getElementsByName("email")(0).Value = "myEmailAddress@test.com" 'enter email
    doc.getElementsByName("password")(0).Value = "myPassword" 'enter password
    doc.getElementsByName("submit")(0).Click 'click log in

End With
```

End Sub`

The first part of it all works fine, it loads up the home page and clicks on the log in button and goes to the login page.

It updates the values on the login page.

[Log In Page filled in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVBDR.png)

but when it performs the click, the page behaves as though the username and password fields are blank, and if I click on the webpage (normally not via vba), the fields go blank and my username and password disappear

[Log In Page after code tries to click Log In Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF2gr.png)

I've tried looking online for a solution and it seems to be a common problem, but I haven't been able to find a fix.

I tried putting this code after assigning values to the fields, but that didn't help

```
Set evt = IE.document.createEvent("keyboardevent")
evt.initEvent "change", True, False
doc.getElementsByName("email")(0).dispatchEvent evt
```

Any suggestions please? This is meant to be the easy part of my project.

Comment: I'am sure you are on the right way. There are html events you must trigger for the input fields. You must know the name of an event. To trigger an event you can use the procedure `TriggerEvent()` from my answer in this posting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61680941/select-an-option-from-a-dropdown-in-ie-and-triggering-a-function/61696514#61696514 You trigger an event with the line `Call TriggerEvent(browser.document, nodeSelect, "change")` The only thing to do is to set your own parameters. If you don't get it to work, you must post the url. If they use jQuery it can fail. Try it :-)

Comment: Thanks Zwenn, I'll take a look at your answer and give it a try
I'm having some success now by using the Selenium addin 

but will definitely look at yours too

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference if anyone else comes across this.

I managed to get around the issue by using the selenium add in.
It mimics button presses better than the method I was using above

referencing the answer posted in this page
[Unable to enter Username and password in webpage using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51578666/unable-to-enter-username-and-password-in-webpage-using-vba?rq=1)